# Get alerts from MySQL to Jenkins when specific data changes

Tags: mysql, jenkins

I have an interesting challenge I am trying to solve.
Say you have a table on MySQL you'd like to know was changed. 
I want to receive an alert of some kind to Jenkins with the details of the change.
At the moment, there's a script that polls the DB and checks wether there was a change. This seems like a not optimal solution. Is there a better way to implement this? Preferably without installing additional software?
Thanks!

Comment: From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917411/send-email-from-mysql-trigger-when-a-table-updated), having the database itself handle this is a way worse idea than what you already have.  I don't have a problem with your current approach.

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen, but I linked in another SO question where sending notifications from mysql had been discussed in more detail. It is possible to send notifications from mysql, but it is neither easy, nor was it ever tested from performance point of view.