# Send Mail after insert new dataset in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, notifications

I just want to get an email notification after a new dataset was inserted in my MYSQL database (using phpMyAdmin).

Unfortunately, I am not yet allowed to insert pics here.

My database has a counter, that counts automatically the entries, and there are three entries I would like to send to a specific email address. So when the counter has a new highest entry an email notification should be pushed.

Thanks for Your help.
Kind regards,
Andy

Comment: 'Unfortunately'? It's a blessing. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code and data as text.

Comment: MySQL doesn't send email, also a blessing. You'll need to write some code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917411/send-email-from-mysql-trigger-when-a-table-updated